# Is there a "vector" notation for pitch, roll, yaw?

Tags: notation, angle

I am looking for a notational shorthand to describe the pitch, roll, and yaw in an paper. Something akin to the $\vec{v} = (x,y,z)$ format for the position variables.

Is there a standard variable I would use for a vector, e.g.  $\vec{k} = (\theta, \phi, \omega)$. Or would you just define a 6 vector $(x,y,z,\theta, \phi, \omega)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles